# Fire backspace event on textbox using Javascript code

Tags: javascript, textbox, dom-events, backspace

Is it possible to fire backspace event on textbox using Javascript?
Which should clear the character left to the cursor position.
I know that event code for backspace is 8 but I don't know how to fire it using the code.

Solution specific to Internet Explorer 8 would be of great help.

Comment: why not programmatically modifying the textbox to clear the character ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this related question: [Simulate JavaScript Key Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

Personally, I think it would be a better, cleaner approach to edit the text directly, removing the char before the cursor position.
See [How to get caret position in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea)

Answer (score -2):

Would be a lot easier to simply trim the value by one character from the end..

```
var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("id");
TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value.substring(0, TheTextBox.length - 1);
```

Comment: textbox.innerHtml == undefined

Comment: You're supposed to populate that value yourself! It just needs to reference the textarea you want to update, I can't do it as you haven't provided any code/details about the textarea (ID mainly).

Comment: Do mean textbox.value? <input type="text" /> doesn't posses 'innerHtml' property

Comment: In that case, use `input.value`, I assumed textbox = textarea

Comment: No cursor position can be anything. Let's say the text inside textbox is "Foo| Bar" where cursor is located after o then after firing thie backspace event text inside textbox should become "Fo Bar". This can't be achieved using value.substring(0, value.length - 1)